# Laurent Series and Taylor Series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion, mathematical-physics, laurent-series

I am trying to find the Laurent series of $\dfrac{1}{(1+x)^3}$; would this be the same as finding the Maclaurin series for the same function?

Comment: Laurent expansion **about** $x=0$ is the familiar Maclaurin series.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So I use the Maclaurin expansion for all poles then?

Comment: If you are expanding about $x=-1$, the Taylor series is irrelevant.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So suppose the function were instead $\dfrac{1}{x(1+x)^3}$, poles therefore at -1 and at 0, and I want Laurent series for $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, what series would be relevant?

Comment: @user1535776 around which point do you want to expand to a series?

Comment: @LiorB-S I want to find the Laurent series about $z = 0$ & $z= 2$, for the function $\dfrac{1}{z(z-2)^3}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to verify this function $f(z)=\dfrac{1}{(z+1)^3}$ has and only has one pole of order 3 at $z=-1$, if one wants to expand it about the pole $z=-1$, two formulas should be took into account.

1. the coefficient formula of Laurent Seriers
   $$ c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \dfrac{f(z)\mathrm{d}z}{(z+1)^{n+1}}$$
2. The well-known formula in complex analysis textbook: 
   $$I=\oint_c\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^{m+1}}\mathrm{d}z=\left\{
   \begin{array}{cc}
   2\pi i,& \;\;m=0\\
   0, &\;\;m\ne 0
   \end{array}\right.$$

You can get that  only the coefficient of $c_{-3}\ne 0, c_{-3}=1 $, all others coefficients are zero, noting $\mathrm{res}f(-1)=c_{-1}=0$.

Therfore the Laurent Series of this fucntion is itself.
$$ f(z)= (z+1)^{-3} $$

If you expand it about $ z \ne -1$, the Laurent series is the same as Taylor series because of the property of ordinary points.

Comment: For expanding about it pole of this function,  I think it can be obtained the answer more directly from the unique theorem of Laurent Series.